# How can i randomly copy files and images from a directory to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

My directory has hundreds of images and text files(`.png` and `.txt`).
what's special about them is that each image has its own matching txt file, for example `im1.png` has `img1.txt`, `news_im2.png` has `news_im2.png` etc..
What i want is some way to give it a parameter or percentage, let's say 40 where it randomly copy 40% of the images along with their correspondent texts to a new file, and the most important word here is randomely as if i do the test again i shouldn't get the same results.
Ideally i should be able to take 2 kind of parameters(reminder that the first would be the % of each sample) the second being number of samples for example maybe i want my data in 3 different samples randomly not only 2, in this case it should be able to take destination directories path equal to the number of samples i want and spread them accordingly, for example i shouldn't find img_1 in 2 different samples.

What i have done so far is simply set up my method to copy them because i couldn't find any random way to do my task in this example it would only copy images:

```
import glob, os, shutil


source_dir ='all_the_content/'
dest_dir = 'percentage_only/'
files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(source_dir, "*.png"))
for file in files:
     if os.path.isfile(file):
         shutil.copy2(file, dest_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

despite of your scenario about handling files, actually your requirement is about sampling, so better not rebuild the wheels, sklearn's [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) provide some ways to handle samplings, hoping it can help you. Through the parameter test_size you can decide how much to be used as samples.

Comment: Not really useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #Idea is to link images and txt files then have them mapped to numbers so 
 that you can have random sampling on numbers and then use it for image 
 sampling
 # You can read all the filenames to a dict, 
 # Using os.lisdir() you can read and filter files
 imgs_dict = {'img1.png' : 'img1.txt'} 
 #and then create a list with keys 
 imgs_list = imgs_dict.keys()
 # Now use random 
 import random
 img_sample_indxs = random.sample(range(1, 100), 40)
```

then continue with copy